# disallow Search on Empty form field

Tags: javascript

I have a form field and I have to see that search button is clicked only when there is some 
data in the form field.
The following is the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsEmptySearch(TxtField){
        var re = /\s/g; //any white space
        var str = TxtField.replace(re, "");
        if (str.length == 0) {
        return true;
        } else {return false;}
        } 
    </script>

<div>
<form id="formsearch" name="formsearch"  />
<input type="text" name="TxtField" maxlength="255" class="findSearch" value="Enter Search..." 
  onfocus="if (this.className=='findSearch') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }"
  onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.className = 'findSearch'; this.value = 'Enter Search...'; }"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="return IsEmptySearch()" >
</form>
</div>
```

The above is not working, as the form gets submitted, even though the Search field is empty.

On Debug the error is showing at "onclick="return IsEmptySearch()" "
 kindly help.

Comment: _What_ is not working? What is _supposed_ to happen that isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
onclick="return !IsEmptySearch()"
```

Your function returns `true` if the search is empty, but to stop your form from being submitted, you have to return a `false`. You can rewrite and rename your function too. Try this, enter something in the search box and see if you can submit.

Answer (score 1):

Change function to following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IsEmptySearch(txtField, defaultText){
    var re = /\s/g; //any white space
    defaultText = defaultText || "";
    var txt = txtField.value.replace(re,"");
    var ret = txt != ""  && txt != defaultText.replace(re,"");
    return ret;
}
</script>
```

change button to following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" 
                  onclick="return IsEmptySearch(aTextField,'Enter Search...')" >
```

this will also not fire if textbox has default prompt text.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But when i incorporate the above, the Submit button is completely still when clicked. Also defaultText is not showing in the Search box

Comment: This code nothing to do with the default value. Which browser are you using?