# Wordpress Plugin Custom Search

Tags: search, wordpress

I am trying to modify a Wordpress plugin. Basically the plugin displays job vacancies. The plugin has a search function where you can search via keyword, job industry and salary. The function is:

```
// SEARCH FUNCTION
function bb_search_jobs($job_keyword=null,$job_industry=null,$job_salary=null) {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix;        

    $query      = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . 'bb_jobs ' 
                . 'WHERE CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(date_time, INTERVAL days_to_advertise DAY) ';

    if($job_keyword != 'null') {
        if(strlen ( $job_keyword ) > 4 ){
            $query .= 'AND MATCH (job_title,job_skills,job_description) AGAINST ("' . esc_sql($job_keyword) . '") ';
        } else {
            $query .= 'AND job_title LIKE "%' . esc_sql($job_keyword) . '%" ';          
        }
    }

    if($job_industry && $job_industry != 'null' ){
        $query .= 'AND job_industry LIKE "%' . esc_sql($job_industry) . '%" ';
    }

    if($job_salary && $job_salary != 'null' ){

        $job_salary = format_salary($job_salary);
        $query .= 'AND salary_from <= "' . esc_sql($job_salary) . '" ';
        $query .= 'AND salary_to >= "' . esc_sql($job_salary) . '" ';
    }

//      var_dump ( $query );

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    return $myrows;

}
```

This search function works but my problem is that if a user doesn't put anything in the 'keyword' input then the search returns all results regardless of whether or not they select an industry or a salary.
I want to modify this function so that the user doesn't have to add a keyword if they don't want to, they could just search via a specific industry or salary and the results would show jobs just from that industry or with that salary.

The URL that is returned ends in ?job_keyword=&job_industry=null
I have noticed that if I manually place a '+' after job_keyword= then the search works. So, how can I modify the function so that if the customer doesn't input anything into the keyword input then the URL displays ?job_keyword=+&job_industry=null instead of ?job_keyword=&job_industry=null

You can view the site along with the plugin at http://www.bettondesignwork.co.uk/castlewp/job-search/

As ever, any help us greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for having a look at this function for my but the problem lay with a bug elsewhere in the plugin. I have now fixed the bug and this function works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Prior to submitting the results to your function, you check for an empty field ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381265/better-way-to-check-variable-for-null-or-empty-string)). I the field is empty, simply change it into "+" prior to submitting it to the function.
2. Via JS, check the form field prior to submitting your form. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158383/disallow-search-on-empty-form-field)